# Sending Promise data from useEffect to another useEffect in React

Tags: reactjs

I am kind of new to React and I wonder how I should work with a data that is coming from a backend.
So lets say I have a function component and inside the function component I have used useState and I have 2 useEffect.
here is the code:

```
//inside the function component
{
    const [data, dataSet] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
            const getLiveData = async () => {
                const URL = "http://localhost:9000/iett/B-138"
                const liveData = await axios.get(URL)
                //console.log("works?", liveData) // working
                dataSet(liveData)
            }
            getLiveData()
        }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
            // I am now using the data in here!
            console.log("data is not working!", data )
        }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following, I hope it will solve your problem

```
useEffect(() => {
            // I am now using the data in here!
            if(data.length){
                  console.log("data is not working!", data )
            }
        }, [data])
```

Here we set dependency as second parameter of `useEffect(),` which means callback function of `useEffect` will get call when `data` get change from anywhere

Comment: Thanks but console.log() runs 2 times. One with empty response and another with response

Comment: I edit my answer check again, you can have if condition before `console.log()`, and also accept and upvote answer if it help you

Comment: `if(data)` will always be true because its first initialized with an empty array. You whould write `if (data.length)` instead

Comment: I get it. my mistake, I updated my answer.